# How do I add a string and an int object in Python?

Tags: python

**What do I need?**

I have SQL content like:

```
('a', 1),
```

So I do:

```
return_string = '('
    for column in columns:
        return_string += "'" + column + "', "
    return_string = return_string[:-2] + '),'
    return return_string
```

But it fails with the same error.

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> a + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>> 1 + "1"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

However, if I convert an int into a string, everything works and I get:

```
('a', '1'),
```

But I need

```
('a', 1),
```

where 1 is unquoted `'`

Answer (score 7):

String concatenation in Python only works between strings. It doesn't infer types based on need like other languages.

There are two options, cast the integer to a strings and add it all together:

```
>>> x ="a"
>>> y = 1
>>> "(" + x + "," + str(y) + ")"
'(a,1)'
>>> "('" + x + "'," + str(y) + ")"
"('a',1)"
>>> "(" + repr(x) + "," + str(y) + ")"
"('a',1)"
```

Or use string formatting to take care of some of this behind the scenes. Either using [(deprecated) "percent formatting"](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> "(%s,%d)"%(x,y)
'(a,1)'
>>> "('%s',%d)"%(x,y)
"('a',1)"
>>> "(%s,%d)"%(repr(x),y)
"('a',1)"
```

Or the more [standard and approved format mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> "({0},{1})".format(x, y)
'(a,1)'
>>> "('{0}',{1})".format(x, y)
"('a',1)"
>>> "({0},{1})".format(repr(x), y)
"('a',1)"
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Percent is quicker to type and get an answer up. Once its in I always add format after (I can never remember some of the more interesting syntax of it).

Comment: @KonradRudolph percent is also quicker execution!

Comment: @mhlester Do you have statistics to prove this? Even so, “correct” is better than “fast but broken”, and the documentation says specifically that “… [% substitutions] are obsolete and **may go away in future versions** of Python”.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, yes, but hard to fit in a comment: `timeit(lambda: "('%s', %d)" % ('a', 1), number=1000000)` and `timeit(lambda: "('{0}', {1})".format('a', 1), number=1000000)` format took 35% longer. I may be mistaken but think they undepricated it for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

It finally clicked what you want and what your input is! It's for arbitrary length columns object! Here you go:

```
return_string = "(" + ', '.join((repr(column) for column in columns)) + ")"
```

Output is exactly as requested:

```
('a', 1)
```

All previous answers (including my deleted one), were assuming a fixed two-item input. But reading your code (and wading through the indent corruption), I see you want any `columns` object to be represented.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to represent your type correctly:

```
def toStr(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return str(x)
    #another elif for others types
    else:
        return "'"+x+"'"
```

And use

```
myTuple = ('a', 1, 2, 5)
print "("+", ".join(toStr(x) for x in myTuple)+")"
```

to print in the correct format.

Answer (score -1):

```
class StrInt:

    def __init__(self, strin, inte):

        self.strin = strin
        self.inte = inte
    def add(self, a, b):

       self.strin = a
       self.inte = b
       wordNum =  f"{a} {b}"
       print(wordNum)

strInt = StrInt("Word", 2)
 
strInt.add(120, "cars") 

print(type(strInt)
```

How many word are we talking about. I came up class which adds a word and a number using f". The function in the class adds a word and and integer.

Comment: Please don't stress that your answer may be wrong, it distracts from your solution. If it is wrong, then others will point it out in the comments and by voting, and you can then delete your answer if you wish.

Comment: The only thing of actual value here is `f"{a} {b}"`, that class wrapper does nothing.