# adding two numbers that are in variables

Tags: python, concatenation

I just started working with python 3 and I'm using a command shell.  Why is there an exception with the code below?

```
 name = input("whats your name: ")
 age = input("what is your age: ")
 work = input("how long will you be working: ")
 print("Good luck " + name + " you will be " + int(age) + int(work) + " years old")
```

Python debugger generates error "should be str vs int".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: how to add string and int object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271225/python-how-to-add-string-and-int-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `string + integer` doesn't work (for good reason). Instead we need to convert back to a string in your method.

But don't write strings like that. As you can see it is pretty error prone. Instead, use string formatting

```
print("Good luck {} you will be {} years old".format(name, int(age) + int(work)))
```

or even better in python 3.6

```
print(f"Good luck {name} you will be {int(age) + int(work)} years old")
```

Comment: print(f... was most effective thank you for the switch syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("Good luck " + name + " you will be " + str(int(age)) + int(work)) + " years old")
```

Most likely because you are concatenating strings and adding ints at the same time. Add them together then convert to string and concatintate afterwards.

Answer (score -2):

Ideally you are converting the `str` to `int` by `int(age)` and again trying to concatenate string with integer. By default, the input() gets the data in string.

please avoid using int() conversion. Also if needed check type(var) and try to concatenate.

Comment: @FHTMitchell, there is no problem in int conversion, actually the age should be integer, as well work. However, the problem is with String concatenation. If you are converting to 'int', then you have to again convert to 'str' in order to concatenate with other string. Hope you understand.

Comment: You said "please avoid using int conversion" Why?

Comment: there is no problem in conversion to int, with respect to your logic. But the point is concatenate string and string and not string and int.